# Ubuntu kernel update password doesn't do anything

Tags: kernel

Over the past few months, every time a new Ubuntu kernel is installed through Software Updates, the process asks for a password to be created. The screen suggests that on reboot I will be asked to use this password. However all that happens is that the blue MOK screen appears, which I ignore and carry on to boot Ubuntu.
Does this mean kernel isn't actually installed?  Grub seems to indicate the latest kernal is there.  The system is using dual boot with Windows 10.

Comment: see here : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2330790

Comment: The suggested thread does not cover same issue as mentioned in my post. But thanks anyway